# What is command! -bang -nargs=* in a vimrc file?

Tags: vimrc

I read a [*document*](https://medium.com/@crashybang/supercharge-vim-with-fzf-and-ripgrep-d4661fc853d2) about vim and the author suggest a line of code that should be put in .vimrc but I totally have no idea what it is.

```
command! -bang -nargs=* Find call fzf#vim#grep('rg --column --line-number --no-heading --fixed-strings --ignore-case --no-ignore --hidden --follow --glob "!.git/*" --color "always" '.shellescape(<q-args>), 1, <bang>0)
```

So what is `command!`, `-bang`, `-nargs`,etc?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As always, the help is your best friend:

[`:h :command`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3acommand):

> `:com[mand][!] [{attr}...] {cmd} {rep}`
>
> Define a user command.  The name of the command is
>   {cmd} and its replacement text is {rep}.  The command's
>   attributes (see below) are {attr}.  If the command
>   already exists, an error is reported, unless a ! is
>   specified, in which case the command is redefined.

Thus `:command!` is used to create a new command that you can use from the command line. Here the new command is `:Find` and it is used to execute `fzf#vim#grep()` which is a call to the plugin [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) which will allow to fuzzy find some files.

The other arguments are described in the documentation:

- [`:h :command-nargs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3acommand-nargs) `-nargs` is used to make the new command able to take an argument `:Find arg1`
- [`:h :command-bang`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3acommand-bang) `-bang` is used to make the new command able to interpret a `!` like in `:Find!`

The `!` right after `command` is used to tell vim to redefine the command if it already exists, this way when you source your `.vimrc` you don't have an error message.

As for the arguments passed to the `fzf` function, I'll let you read the doc of the plugin to see what they do :)

Comment: You answer's more precise than doc. So if I don't have fzf installed, that said I'd like to define a simpler command, this command `command! -bang -nargs=* Find 'rg --column --line-number --no-heading --fixed-strings --ignore-case --no-ignore --hidden --follow --glob "!.git/*" --color "always"'` will work?

Comment: @TuyenPham probably not: the code in your comment creates a command `Find` which will be replaced by `rg --column etc...` but `rg` is not a vim command it is an argument to the `fzf` function so Vim will echo an error. If you want an example of a simple command see this one: `command! DT windo diffthis`. It creates the command `:DT` which doesn't take an argument or anything and which starts the diffmode in vim. The `{rep}` part of the command must be an expression that vim understands.

Comment: I believe what Tuyen was referring to in rg is ripgrep, another tool as opposed to FZF.